# Await list of async predicates, but drop out on first false

Tags: c#, .net, linq, async-await, enumeration

Imagine the following class:

```
public class Checker
{
   public async Task<bool> Check() { ... }
}
```

Now, imagine a list of instances of this class:

```
IEnumerable<Checker> checkers = ...
```

Now I want to control that every instance will return `true`:

```
checkers.All(c => c.Check());
```

Now, this won't compile, since `Check()` returns a `Task<bool>` not a `bool`.

So my question is: How can I best enumerate the list of checkers?
And how can I shortcut the enumeration as soon as a checker returns `false`?
(something I presume `All( )` does already)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And how can I shortcut the enumeration as soon as a checker returns false?

This will check the tasks' result in order of completion. So if task #5 is the first to complete, and returns false, the method returns false immediately, regardless of the other tasks. Slower tasks (#1, #2, etc) would never be checked.

```
public static async Task<bool> AllAsync(this IEnumerable<Task<bool>> source)
{
    var tasks = source.ToList();

    while(tasks.Count != 0)
    {
        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        if(! finishedTask.Result)
            return false;

        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool result = await checkers.Select(c => c.Check())
                            .AllAsync();
```

Comment: Is there a reason for why you first `select` and then `AllAsync` instead of combining them as @I3arnon does in his answer?

Comment: @Vegar No special reason, but I thought that, if you're gonna write one (`AllAsync()`) or the other (`AllAsync(Func<T, bool)`), you might as well pick the most basic building block, which can then be composed with a `Select` if need be. Writing the other one is a trivial task. If you were asked to choose between `Sum()` (which can then be composed with `.Select().Sum()` if a projection is needed) or `Sum(Func<T, int>)` (for which a projection is always required, even if your enumerable is *already* a collection of ints), which one would you choose? I just think the first is more flexible.

Comment: ok. Even though I like 'fluent compositions', I still like my train as short as possible. ;-)

Comment: @Vegar You can always have both extension methods, for maximum flexibility/readability :) It's just a matter of changing the signature a bit and the first line to `var tasks = source.Select(predicate).ToList();`

Answer (score 10):

"Asynchronous sequences" can always cause some confusion. For example, it's not clear whether your desired semantics are:

1. Start all checks simultaneously, and evaluate them as they complete.
2. Start the checks one at a time, evaluating them in sequence order.

There's a third possibility (start all checks simultaneously, and evaluate them in sequence order), but that would be silly in this scenario.

I recommend using Rx for asynchronous sequences. It gives you a lot of options, and it a bit hard to learn, but it also forces you to think about exactly what you want.

The following code will start all checks simultaneously and evaluate them as they complete:

```
IObservable<bool> result = checkers.ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(c => c.Check()).All(b => b);
```

It first converts the sequence of checkers to an observable, calls `Check` on them all, and checks whether they are all `true`. The first `Check` that completes with a `false` value will cause `result` to produce a `false` value.

In contrast, the following code will start the checks one at a time, evaluating them in sequence order:

```
IObservable<bool> result = checkers.Select(c => c.Check().ToObservable())
    .Concat().All(b => b);
```

It first converts the sequence of checkers to a sequence of observables, and then concatenates those sequences (which starts them one at a time).

If you do not wish to use observables much and don't want to mess with subscriptions, you can `await` them directly. E.g., to call `Check` on all checkers and evaluate the results as they complete:

```
bool all = await checkers.ToObservable().SelectMany(c => c.Check()).All(b => b);
```

Comment: RX is one of several 'I understand that this would be good for me, but my brain hurts'-areas for me. Especially if you add RxUI on top of it ;-)

Comment: I am new to `Rx` and i am not sure, how does `Rx` `await` the result in the statement `checkers.ToObservable().SelectMany(c => c.Check()).All(b => b)`. I can see one can `await` an `IObservable` but not sure how it all happens.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the semantics. Other answers assume only one option.

Comment: @NedStoyanov: When you `await` an observable, the code (asynchronously) waits for the observable to complete and returns the last value as a result.

Answer (score 3):

`All` wasn't built with `async` in mind (like all `LINQ`), so you would need to implement that yourself:

```
async Task<bool> CheckAll()
{
    foreach(var checker in checkers)
    {
        if (!await checker.Check())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You could make it more reusable with a generic extension method:

```
public static async Task<bool> AllAsync<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<bool>> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!await predicate(item))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var result = await checkers.AllAsync(c => c.Check());
```

Comment: Isn't this awaiting in order unlike the semantics of Task.WhenAll? I would assume dcastro's and Cleary's answer are faster.

Comment: @nawfal probably, yes. It depends on whether the individual checks are allowed to run concurrently, which isn't necessarily true, but I don't remember the context as that was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
checkers.All(c => c.Check().Result);
```

but that would run the tasks synchronously, which may be very slow depending on the implementation of `Check()`.

Comment: The second option will make the delegate `async void` which should almost [never be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: well, it doesn't work anyway, as I just tested it.  Thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully functional test program, following in steps of dcastro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncCheckerTest
{
    public class Checker
    {
        public int Seconds { get; private set; }

        public Checker(int seconds)
        {
            Seconds = seconds;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CheckAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(Seconds * 1000);
            return Seconds != 3;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = RunAsync();
            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Overall result: " + task.Result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<bool> RunAsync()
        {
            var checkers = new List<Checker>();
            checkers
                .AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                .Select(i => new Checker(i)));

            return await checkers
                            .Select(c => c.CheckAsync())
                            .AllAsync();
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static async Task<bool> AllAsync(this IEnumerable<Task<bool>> source)
        {
            var tasks = source.ToList();

            while (tasks.Count != 0)
            {
                Task<bool> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

                bool checkResult = finishedTask.Result;

                if (!checkResult)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Completed at " + DateTimeOffset.Now + "...false");
                    return false;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Working... " + DateTimeOffset.Now);
                tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's sample output:

```
Working... 6/27/2014 1:47:35 AM -05:00
Working... 6/27/2014 1:47:36 AM -05:00
Completed at 6/27/2014 1:47:37 AM -05:00...false
Overall result: False
```

Note that entire eval ended when exit condition was reached, without waiting for the rest to finish.

Comment: I realize that I could use Progress<T> to update the console, and it would be better in production.  I am trying to illustrate the fact that async/await works even if there's no "current sync context" to revert to.

Answer (score -1):

As a more out-of-the-box alternative, this seems to run the tasks in parallel and return shortly after the first failure:

```
var allResult = checkers
    .Select(c => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Check().Result))
    .AsParallel()
    .All(t => t.Result);
```

I'm not too hot on TPL and PLINQ so feel free to tell me what's wrong with this.

Comment: I would suspect your program will block once ThreadPool runs dry.  Thread pool is best used when compute-intensive work is scheduled.  If each async check takes a relatively long time, then this will take considerably longer than other implementations.

Comment: @GregC Fair enough, I knew it seemed too simple :)

Comment: The point of using `async` is to not block threads unnecessarily, which is exactly what this does. And the `StartNew()` doesn't make any sense, if it was just `Select(c => c.Check())` it would work just as well and without blocking any threads.

Comment: @svick I tried that, it just hung indefinitely. As is, this does run threads in parallel.